# Why do these tabs seem to share the same textbox?

Tags: c#

I defined my UI in xaml and below is my code:

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="330" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="764" Margin="10,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="16" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            </TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
```

When I ran my program. I could add many tabs with no problem. The headers are different but whenever I change the content of textbox in one of tabs, all the textboxes in other tabs changed to the same content (Seems like they were all sharing the same textbox, or binding to the same source, which is wierd).

Did I make a mistake defining the UI? Please help me and thanks in advance.

This is my model, really simple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyHomework__MVVM_
{
    class MyHomeworkModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string header, text;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Header
        {
            get
            {
                return header;
            }
            set
            {
                header = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Header");
            }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return text;
            }
            set
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my viewmodel, which is still really simple:

```
using MyHomework;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyHomework__MVVM_
{
    class MyHomeworkViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> allTabs;
        private MyHomeworkModel selectedTab;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MyHomeworkViewModel()
        {
            allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();
            selectedTab = new MyHomeworkModel();
            AddCourseCommand = new AddCourseCommand(this);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> AllTabs
        {
            get
            {
                return allTabs;
            }
            set
            {
                allTabs = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AllTabs");
            }
        }

        public MyHomeworkModel SelectedTab
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedTab;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedTab = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTab");
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddCourseCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public void AddNewTab()
        {
            NewCourseName ncn = new NewCourseName();
            ncn.ShowDialog();
            if (ncn.courseName != null)
            {
                MyHomeworkModel newTab = new MyHomeworkModel();
                newTab.Header = ncn.courseName;
                newTab.Text = ncn.courseName;
                AllTabs.Add(newTab);
                SelectedTab = newTab;
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Just noticed that I got this message:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'object' ''MyHomeworkViewModel' (HashCode=31265986)'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem='MyHomeworkViewModel' (HashCode=31265986); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

I think I know why it's complaining. My Text property is is MyHomeworkModel not MyHomeworkViewModel...but why it's fine with me binding the header to the Header property in MyHomeworkModel ?

My AddCourseCommand class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyHomework__MVVM_
{
    class AddCourseCommand : ICommand
    {
        private MyHomeworkViewModel viewModel;

        public AddCourseCommand(MyHomeworkViewModel viewModel)
        {
            this.viewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            viewModel.AddNewTab();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No there is no Problem with your XAML code, can you please add your ViewModel and Model?

Comment: The same Code? or have you changed it?

Comment: Yes.  I changed my model....same problem

Comment: I don't get that binding error when I added my first tab. I did when i added the second one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Model implement

```
ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>.
```

Remove this Base class and it should work.

**Edit**:

Your need to change:

```
       AddCourseCommand = new AddCourseCommand(this);
```

To

Download [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)

```
       AddCourseCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddNewTab);
```

**Edit:**

You Cut your ViewModel from your UI. You Copy an Instance into your Command and than call on that Copy add. This is wrong and Property your Fault. I realy advice you to use DelegateCommand this will maybe fix it.

To your guess:

> think I know why it's complaining. My Text property is is MyHomeworkModel not MyHomeworkViewModel...but why it's fine with me binding the header to the Header property in MyHomeworkModel ?

It is right that your Property is in `MyHomeworkModel` and not in `MyHomeworkViewModel` you Bind onto a List that contains `MyHomeworkModel`s. Now is you add a new item your Binding will set in the Lowest level. In this case in your insance of `MyHomeworkModel` and not in `MyHomeworkViewModel`

Comment: But this is the model for my collection of tabs, right? If I remove it, I won't have any object to add my tabs to.

Comment: The first is right but the second is wrong. Your Model should Implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you want to change your Propertys in your code, but if you Inherit from ObservableCollection every Time you change your Property, this base class will inform all Other Propertys that they are changed. You can add every Object to an ObservableCollection if its of the Same Type like this Type-Paramter ObservableCollection<Type-Paramter>. You better should inform your self about [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: AddNewTab() is void because it just adds a new HomeworkModel object to the collection and this change will be reflected on the UI....besides my AddCourseCommand constructor takes a viewmodel object as paramater..

Comment: That make no Sense. ICommand ist just an simple Interface and you can't instance an interface! Thats hurts OOP rules HARD! And there is no allocation of AddCourseCommand with AddNewTab. It should never run into the function!

Comment: Please show the Implementation of the Class. For Now it seems like you Instance your interface with a new Instance of it self and thats nonsense.