# BindingExpression path error？

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do these tabs seem to share the same textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402821/why-do-these-tabs-seem-to-share-the-same-textbox)

My Header and Text properties are both in MyHomeworkModel class.
I'm setting my view's datacontext to MyHomeworkViewModel class.
However, in my view, I'm binding the newly added tab header and textbox text to those two properties in MyHomeworkModel.

Then I get BindingExpression path error whenever I tried to **add the second tab**, and it only complains about my binding to Text, no complaining about binding to Header.

I still get the second tab, except for the fact that all my textboxes (in different tabs) have the same text.

Below is my xaml:

```
 <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="330" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="764" Margin="10,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="16" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                </TextBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
```

Comment: what? post the viewmodel or code behind. Also, you have a conceptual problem here: a `TabControl` is an `ItemsControl`, therefore it should be bound to some `List<T>`, not to individual string properties or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Exact [Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402821/why-do-these-tabs-seem-to-share-the-same-textbox/14402994#comment20040322_14402994) please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)!

Comment: Sorry if you considered this as a duplicate, but I feel like here I'm asking a more specific question. Besides the fact that people seemed to be confused about my explanation.

Comment: You post the Excatly same Code, ask the same Question. The first Question is not Confused. I edit my Answer in the Orignial